# Disable logging for a particular package

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am implementing python logging in my application, and I want to be able to leverage the "default" root settings.  I want to use root settings because I dont want to have to define a logger per module in a config file.

When I turn on DEBUG level logging for the root logger, I am running into an issue with the QPID Python Client API. My log files get flooded with qpid debug statements:

> 2011-03-16 09:16:18,664 - qpid.messaging.io.ops - DEBUG - SENT[8de6b2c]: ..
>
> 2011-03-16 09:16:18,667 - qpid.messaging.io.raw - DEBUG - ..
>
> 2011-03-16 09:16:18,668 - qpid.messaging.io.raw - DEBUG - READ[8de6b2c]: ..
>
> 2011-03-16 09:16:18,668 - qpid.messaging.io.ops - DEBUG - ..

Etc..

So two main questions:

1) Is there a way to enable* logging for just my modules without defining a logger per module? In other words is there a way to do shared "logger settings," so instead of having to define a logger_ section per logger is there a way to default the settings?

Something like:

```
[logger_shared_settings]
    loggers = logger_A,logger_B,logger_C,logger_D
    level=DEBUG
```

2) Or How can i filter out the qpid package logging via a config file?

Here is the log.conf file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler,nullHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('out.log',)
```

---

Here was what I was trying to avoid:

```
[loggers]
keys=root, a, b, c, d

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler,nullHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=ERROR
handlers=nullHandler


[logger_a]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler


[logger_b]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[logger_c]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With python2.7 you can set NullHandler to qpid logger:

```
[logger_qpid]
level=NOTSET
handlers=nullHandler
qualname=qpid
propagate=0
```

Comment: Hmmm... what means "shared settings"?

Comment: Kind of like the root logger, but a different section which I could apply the the modules in my application.

Comment: This is impossible because of the hierarchical structure of the loggers, but I guess, that in python2.7 you can try create your own config based on dictConfig feature of logging module.

Comment: How does adding null handler to child logger prevent root logger from displaying log messages?

Comment: handler is required, so it's set to nullHandler, actual works here done by "propagate" param.