# How to implement different levels for specific modules in Python

Tags: logging, module, python-2.x

From this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326012/disable-logging-for-a-particular-package), how does one implement the following configuration file?

```
[logger_qpid]
level=NOTSET
handlers=nullHandler
qualname=qpid
propagate=0
```

I am using logging.basicConfig:

```
# Configure parser.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Allow for debug logging mode.')
parser.add_argument('--debug', action = 'store_true',
                    help = 'Outputs additional information to log.')
c_args = parser.parse_args()
# Configure logging mode.
if c_args.debug:
    # Enable debug level of logging.
    print "Logging level set to debug."
    logging.basicConfig(filename = LOG_FILENAME, format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                        level = logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(filename = LOG_FILENAME, format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                        level = logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the suds package's documentation site, you can set the level for a specific package by using the setLevel method.  For example, here's how to set the level of all suds logging to INFO level (place after `logging.basicConfig()` code):

```
logging.getLogger('suds').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: or use it like

```>>>
import mymodule
logging.getLogger(mymodule.__name__)
```