# Suppress InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made in Python2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6, suppress-warnings, urllib3, pyvmomi

I am writing scripts in Python2.6 with use of [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) and while using one of the connection methods:

```
service_instance = connect.SmartConnect(host=args.ip,
                                        user=args.user,
                                        pwd=args.password)
```

I get the following warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:734: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

What's interesting is that I do not have urllib3 installed with pip (but it's there in */usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/*).

I have tried as suggested [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html)

```
import urllib3
...
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

but that didn't change anything.

Comment: You might try setting the log level for that specific module as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234262/how-to-implement-different-levels-for-specific-modules-in-python

Comment: A global and completly working solution is there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463277/how-to-disable-python-warnings

Comment: **WARNING:** only disable certificate validation **if you don't care about someone impersonating the remote server!**

Comment: well, the warning doesn't really *prevent* whatever's happening. It's not disabling validation, it's disabling the warning about the lack of validation.

Answer (score 1186, accepted):

You can disable any Python warnings via the `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable. In this case, you want:

```bash
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"
```

To disable using Python code (`requests >= 2.16.0`):

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

For `requests < 2.16.0`, see original answer below.

**Original answer**

The reason doing `urllib3.disable_warnings()` didn't work for you is because it looks like you're using a separate instance of urllib3 vendored inside of requests.

I gather this based on the path here: `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py`

To disable warnings in requests' vendored urllib3, you'll need to import that specific instance of the module:

```
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: I blog about the development I do on pyvmomi and covered this issue back in October 2014. Im just sharing this link to help others find useful pyvmomi info in the future: http://www.errr-online.com/index.php/tag/pyvmomi/

Comment: `PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"`

Comment: For completeness: `from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning`

Comment: Why does this work but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library) doesnt

Comment: This answer is outdated. For a modern version, see Nayana Adassuriya's answer.

Comment: Copied from Nayana Adassuriya's answer: `import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)`.

Comment: This doesn't work with elasticsearch probably due to context disparity

Comment: Is there a way to restore the warning state to the one before `rllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)` was called? Or maybe just disable them on per request basis, i.e. `requests.get(url, disable_warnings=InsecureRequestWarning,  **some_args)`

Comment: saved my day! works with Python 3.6 perfectly! used it to suppress warnings while connecting to aws.

Comment: @shazow , What happened security point of you, If we setup 'verify=False` with getting warning `Unverified HTTP request..` ? another, If I set `verify=True` then request not work , getting error like `request.exception.SSError..Max retries exceeded with url:` ? which one best solution.

Comment: The import worked form: '''import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)'''

Answer (score 184):

This is the answer in 2017. `urllib3` not a part of `requests` anymore

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: The year is less import than the revision number of python you are using.

Comment: Yeah, revision more important than year. This is for `requests >= 2.16.0`

Comment: can someone post the version of urllib3, when i try this, it says urllib3 has no attribute 'disable_warnings'

Comment: I am confused by this response. My `requests` version is `2.21.0` and it has `urllib3`. I tried `2.16.0`, ` 2.16.1`, and ` 2.17.0` and they all had `urllib3`. I tried `2.4.0` and that one did not have it, though. Did they add it back in?

Comment: @MikeFurlender you are confused because the answer is misleading - although `urllib3` is not _vendored_ by `requests` anymore, it still remains a _dependency_ of `requests`. So the import will still resolve fine and one doesn't need to import `urllib3`. To verify: `python -c 'import requests; print(requests.packages.urllib3.__path__)'` will still print path to `urllib3` package.

Answer (score 67):

Per [this github](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2214#issuecomment-55055597) comment, one can disable `urllib3` request warnings via `requests` in a 1-liner:

`requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()`

This will suppress **all** warnings though, not just `InsecureRequest` (ie it will also suppress `InsecurePlatform` etc).  In cases where we just want stuff to work, I find the conciseness handy.

Comment: This is the best option for 2.7 as I don't need to import urllib3 just to suppress the warning

Comment: `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)` seems to work.

Answer (score 52):

The HTTPS certificate verification security measure isn't something to be discarded light-heartedly. The Man-in-the-middle attack that it prevents safeguards you from a third party e.g. *sipping a virus in* or tampering with or *stealing* your data.
Even if you only intend to do that in a test environment, you can easily forget to undo it when moving elsewhere.

Instead, read [the relevant section on the provided link](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecurerequestwarning) and do as it says. The way specific for `requests` (which bundles with its own copy of `urllib3`), as per [CA Certificates — Advanced Usage — Requests 2.8.1 documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ca-certificates):

- `requests` ships with its own certificate bundle (but it can only be updated together with the module)
- it will use (since `requests` `v2.4.0`) **the `certifi` package** instead if it's installed
- In a test environment, you can easily slip a test certificate into `certifi` as per [how do I update root certificates of certifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869723/how-do-i-update-root-certificates-of-certifi) . E.g. if you replace its bundle with just your test certificate, you will immediately see it if you forget to undo that when moving to production.

Finally, with today's government-backed global hacking operations like [Tailored Access Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailored_Access_Operations) and [the Great Firewall of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Firewall_of_China) that target network infrastructure, falling under a MITM attack is more probable than you think.

Comment: I have requests 2.8.1 and certifi 2015.11.20.1 and I still get the warning.

Comment: @AlexBartiş this can be if you (or some code that you call) pass `verify=False`.

Comment: Why are there so few votes for this answer? Is it actually safe to ignore these warnings?

Comment: @sgryzko Only if you don't care about someone impersonating the remote server. Probably, many indeed don't care and/or don't read beyond the first answer, contributing to the positive feedback cycle. This answer was also posted almost a year later.

Comment: It's not "the correct answer".  It's the "safest general principle" answer.  Sometimes you really do mean to disable verification.  The consumer needs to be aware of the implications, but it's not incorrect.

Comment: @mushuweasel you can suggest an edit if you can think of better wording.

Comment: Yes, you should do the right thing in a production environment, and blindly suppressing the error is bad. But it is a completely valid thing to want to suppress these errors in a test environment.

Comment: If I wanted to be lectured on TLS certificates, I would have followed the link in the error message.

Comment: The solution / answer is missing here . There is just  links annd disputable opinions. Who may judge what is "correct" without looking at specific usecases?

Comment: Agree with the concept of this answer. I am trying to make https call to a domain using LetsEncrypt cert, already have the latest `certifi` installed (`certifi-2021.10.8`). `curl` does not give me SSL cert warning/error, but python does. Still looking for solution.

Answer (score 41):

The accepted answer doesn't work if some package vendors it's own copy of urllib3, in which case this will still work:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')
```

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 24):

For `Python 3.7.9` and `requests 2.11.1`, this is the only way it worked to suppress the specific Exception in the OP:

```py
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(
    requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Not sure why the above worked and this one did not:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Here is a simplification of the working version:

```
from requests.packages import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

... it would appear that the import of `urllib3` directly does not contain the same namespace as the one loaded by `requests` and thus the `disable_warnings` does not mutate the data structure touched by `requests`.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Just to be sure that the warning came back when the 2nd line was commented.

Answer (score 14):

For impatient, a quick way to disable python unverified HTTPS warning:

```bash
export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"
```

Comment: For powershell the command is `$env:PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"`

Answer (score 13):

If you want to disable the warnings, but do not want to silence warnings from other packages, or other parts of your application, here is how to disable them per call.

Step 1, create a context manager.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def disable_ssl_warnings():
    import warnings
    import urllib3

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
        yield None
```

Step 2, wrap your calls:

```py
with disable_ssl_warnings():
    requests.get('https://example.com')
```

The warning will only be silenced for that call.

(As per @shazow's answer, this works with `requests >= 2.16.0`)

Comment: As of 2024/01/09, It's the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

One liner, if you made the `import requests` before :

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Answer (score 6):

That's probably useful for someone, who uses unittest, if imported modules use request library.
To suppress warnings in requests' vendored urllib3, add

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')
```

to setUp method in your testclass, i.e:

```
import unittest, warnings

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')
    
    (all test methods here)
```

Comment: Missing required imports.

Answer (score 6):

Warning message

> ~/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
> InsecureRequestWarning)

In Debian 8 these steps fixed the issue.

1. In python3 code

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

2. Install two packages on Debian

> libssl1.0.0_1.0.2l-1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb

> libssl-dev_1.0.2l-1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb

[debian mirror](https://mirrors.mediatemple.net/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/)
After download above deb packages install with apt.

```bash
apt install ./libssl-dev_1.0.2l-1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb 

apt install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2l-1_bpo8+1_amd64.deb
```

To build dependencies with new library

3. Create new venv for python project

```bash
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Clean Install modules under python project inside virtual environment by

```bash
python3 -m pip install -e .
```

Comment: In Python 3 on windows all I needed was urllib3.disable_warnings().

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with PyVmomi Client. With Python Version 2.7.9, I have solved this issue with the following line of code:

```
default_sslContext = ssl._create_unverified_context()
self.client = \
                Client(<vcenterip>, username=<username>, password=<passwd>,
                       sslContext=default_sslContext )
```

Note that, for this to work, you need Python 2.7.9 atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using pyvmomi [original function](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/36291a377584c37cc04b8bd8e8d65812a56d6c0d/pyVim/connect.py#L858) `SmartConnectNoSSL`.
They [added](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/commit/f91ccde07132103104691ef70cc784fdb950fa32) this function on `June 14, 2016` and named it `ConnectNoSSL`, [one day after](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/commit/82fba028bf978213000ab2ec01327dde9301e474) they changed the name to `SmartConnectNoSSL`, use that instead of by passing the warning with unnecessary lines of code in your project?

> Provides a standard method for connecting to a specified server without SSL
>      verification. Useful when connecting to servers with self-signed certificates
>      or when you wish to ignore SSL altogether

```
service_instance = connect.SmartConnectNoSSL(host=args.ip,
                                             user=args.user,
                                             pwd=args.password)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Python 2.7**

Add the environment variable PYTHONWARNINGS as key and the corresponding value to be ignored like:

`os.environ['PYTHONWARNINGS']="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"`

Answer (score 0):

### Suppress logs using standard python library '*logging*'

---

Place this code on the top of your existing code

```
import logging
urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger('urllib3')
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```