# Why does Python Requests cause InsecureRequestWarning but my browser seems to connect using HTTPS fine?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have seen questions answering how to suppress the warning but I want to understand why the warning happens. I can go to a https site in my browser with no warning about it being insecure but when I try to send requests using python requests I get the warning. Why?

I have seen this explanation: [What does the Python InsecureRequestWarning really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411546/what-does-the-python-insecurerequestwarning-really-mean)

Does this mean my browser has a certificate and requests doesn't?

Comment: That's what it means, yes.

Comment: @deceze So how do I get the certificate so I can point requests to it?

Comment: the cert could also be part of your os store.