# https get request with python urllib2

Tags: python, https, urllib2

I am trying to fetch data from quandl using urllib2.Please check code below.

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib2
import requests
import ssl
#import quandl
codes = [100526];
for id in codes:
    url = 'https://www.quandl.com.com//api/v3/datasets/AMFI/"+str(id)+".json?api_key=XXXXXXXX&start_date=2013-08-30'
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = response.read()
    print data
```

OR

```
for id in codes:
    url = "https://www.quandl.com.com//api/v3/datasets/AMFI/"+str(id)+".json?api_key=XXXXXXXX&start_date=2013-08-30"
    request = requests.get(url,verify=False)
    print request
```

I am getting HTTPERROR exception 404 in 1st case. and when I use request module I get SSL error even after using verify=false. I am looking through previous posts but most of them are related to HTTP request.

Thanks for help.
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a wrong URL (`.com.com` instead of `.com`) as well as a combination of different quotes in the first version of your code. Use the following instead and it should work:

```
import urllib2
import requests

codes = [100526]

for id in codes:
    url = "https://www.quandl.com//api/v3/datasets/AMFI/"+str(id)+".json?start_date=2013-08-30"
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    print response.read()

for id in codes:
    url = "https://www.quandl.com//api/v3/datasets/AMFI/"+str(id)+".json?start_date=2013-08-30"
    response = requests.get(url,verify=False)
    print response.text
```

To disable the warning about the SSL certificate, use [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002687/211221) before making the request using `requests`:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess .com was causing error. And to be sure I have used `request = requests.get(url,cert=('C:\\ssl\\ca.crt', 'C:\\ssl\\ca.key'))
        jsonReq = request.json()`

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me, but you get a warning about the SSL certificate but you don't need to care about it.

```
import requests
codes = [100526];
for id in codes:
    url = "https://www.quandl.com.com//api/v3/datasets/AMFI/"+str(id)+".json?api_key=XXXXXXXX&start_date=2013-08-30"
    request = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    print request.text
```

`request.text` has your response data.