# how do I update root certificates of certifi?

Tags: python, ssl, urllib, root-certificate, certifi

I am using certifi python module to verify ssl connections. I looked at the root certificates included in certifi (python2.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem) and some of those certificates have expired. How do I update those certificates? I tried updating certifi package using pip but that only updates the package and not the root CA files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`certifi/cacert.pem` is, naturally, a part of `certifi`. Consequently, it's supposed to be updated with the module.

- You can check if the latest code at https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi has a newer bundle and if it does, install the module directly from there with `pip install git+https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi`.
- You can also replace `cacert.pem` with any other certificate bundle that meets your needs, like the [Mozilla root certificate store](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). Of course, your changes will be lost the next time you update the module.