# Heroku - ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'

Tags: python, heroku, pipenv

Heroku is suddenly rejecting deployments of my Python app with the error:

```
remote:        ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

This is occurring when deploying completely non-functional changes to what's already running fine on Heroku.

```
✗ git checkout -b testing heroku/master 
Branch testing set up to track remote branch master from heroku.
Switched to a new branch 'testing'
➜  fwdform2 git:(testing) ✗ echo "Garbage" > README.md 
➜  fwdform2 git:(testing) ✗ git add README.md 
➜  fwdform2 git:(testing) ✗ git commit -m "Non-functional changes"
[testing 7dd95cb] Non-functional changes
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 275 deletions(-)
 rewrite README.md (100%)
➜  fwdform2 git:(testing) ✗ git push heroku testing:master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 288 bytes | 288.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with latest Pipenv…
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
remote:            sys.exit(cli())
remote:          File "/tmp/build_ffaa2c482e67c8c4daeb9b3348ef030d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
remote:            return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_ffaa2c482e67c8c4daeb9b3348ef030d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
remote:            rv = self.invoke(ctx)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_ffaa2c482e67c8c4daeb9b3348ef030d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1063, in invoke
remote:            Command.invoke(self, ctx)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_ffaa2c482e67c8c4daeb9b3348ef030d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
remote:            return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_ffaa2c482e67c8c4daeb9b3348ef030d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
remote:            return callback(*args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/tmp/build_ffaa2c482e67c8c4daeb9b3348ef030d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
remote:            return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 62, in cli
remote:            from . import core
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 30, in <module>
remote:            from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
remote:        ImportError: cannot import name 'InsecureRequestWarning'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !    Push rejected to fwdform2.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fwdform2.git
 ! [remote rejected] testing -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fwdform2.git'
```

It looks like Heroku's Python buildpack, specifically pipenv, is broken. Any ideas?

**Python version (runtime.txt):**
3.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug with [Pipenv and Heroku's buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/661), which has since been rectified.

If anyone runs into a similar issue in the future, you can fork [Heroku's buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) and alter the pinned Pipenv version, or make any other necessary changes.

Push your fork, then setup your application to use your forked buildpack e.g.

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/heroku-buildpack-python.git\#7e0da719744f0f5185a624d38877effa142d6639
```

Kenneth Reitz of Salesforce/Heroku also suggested the use of the following commands to purge any Pipenv/buildpack related issues:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:purge_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you please add **python —version** to this workflow and tell us what that is?  I suspect that it is Python < 2.7.9.

See [Suppress InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made in Python2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho)