# How to run Gunicorn on HTTPS on CloudFoundry

Tags: django, ssl, https, cloud-foundry

I need to host my Django application using *gunicorn* on *Cloudfoundry* on port `443`, HTTPS.

I am getting error:

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding
>   certificate verification is strongly advised.

Which is resulting into Internal server error.

How should I add add SSL.

What are `server.cert` and `server.key` files? How to add them.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting error:
>
> > InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.

I don't believe this is related. See this SO post for more details on the error.

[Suppress InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made in Python2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho)

As far as handling HTTPS for your app on Cloud Foundry, good news, there's nothing you need to do. Cloud Foundry will handle TLS termination for incoming requests to your apps. That's it.

If you're curious about the details, there are a lot of them at the following link. The details do depend on how your platform operator has set up TLS termination, so you could also talk with them if you have questions.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/securing-traffic.html

Hope that helps!