# Suppress all InsecureRequestWarnings

Tags: python, suppress-warnings, urllib3

When I try to make a request using:

```
request_arguments = {
    "method": method,
    "url": self._build_url(self.url, action),
    "headers": self._get_headers(**kwargs),
    "data": kwargs["data"] if "data" in kwargs else {},
    "verify": False
}

response = requests.request(**request_arguments)
```

I'm getting the following warning:

```
 tests/end_to_end/test_integration_alert.py::test_mm_put
      /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:858:
        InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.
        See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
        InsecureRequestWarning)
```

I tried to suppress it in the constructor via:

```
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

as described here:

[Suppress InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made in Python2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho)

Interestingly, I still get the warning the first time the code is called, but subsequent calls are correctly suppressed. (I hit the breakpoints in the correct order)

How can I suppress the initial warning as well?

Comment: You say subsequent requests are correctly suppressed, so it would be helpful to see your code. Python version would be helpful as well.

Comment: instead of `urllib3.disable_warnings()` you probably might need `import requests.package.urllib3 as urllib3` and then `urllib3.disable_warnings()`

Comment: @Shan-Desai no, `import requests.package.urllib3 as urllib3` is just a more complicated way to do `import urllib3` since requests >= 2.16.0, see https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.22.0/requests/packages.py