# Python: System CA certificates not recognized by urllib3

Tags: python, ssl, urllib3

When I try to access any HTTP website, even one of the most popular, I get a SSL warning from urllib3 module.

```py
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> http.request("GET", "https://www.google.de")
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:858: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f5251466c90>
>>>
```

Can somebody please help me getting this fixed?

Unfortunately I have to use a API that is apparently using urllib3 under the hood to do the actual REST calls.

So I have to get it fixed w/o avoiding urllib3 module.
I've already checked the ca certificates using `ssl.SSLContext.get_ca_certs()` which contains the CA certificate.
Doing the same with curl or openssl, works without any verification warnings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just suppress the messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho

Comment: Not only since the documentation of **urllib3** writes _Making unverified HTTPS requests is strongly discouraged_, I haveto get it working with the SSL certificate verified. I have to get notice, once there is something wrong with the certificate.

Comment: Did you try to follow the docs for Python 2 & urllib3? https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#certificate-verification-in-python-2

Answer (score 1):

The [urllib3 docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#custom-tls-certificates) explain how to explicitly specify a certificate bundle. You just have to pass the path to your certificates when you initialize `PoolManager()`:

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs="CERT_REQUIRED",
    ca_certs="/path/to/your/certificate_bundle"
)
resp = http.request("GET", "https://example.com")
```

By default it uses the certifi certificate bundle, so you shouldn't even have to do this unless you are using self-signed certificates or a private CA. If you are seeing this problem with popular sites, something is wrong with your CA related environment variables or your certifi bundle, or you are hitting a bug. Upgrade to the latest versions of certifi and urllib3. Some CA related behavior has also changed in recent versions.

Comment: Seems that I was really using a buggy version. Today I cannot reproduce the issue. But the hint with the explicit CA certificate bundle specificiation is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows) that you can run `python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"` to get the default paths used for loading certs.

On Ubuntu, I got this:

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs')
```

I noticed that `/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem` didn't exist on my system, and so created a symbolic link to it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
```

After doing that, urllib3 was able to find the correct ca certs.