# Unable to get local issuer certificate and Max retries exceeded in python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I tried to crawl https://foodtracer.taipei.gov.tw/Front/Chain/Product?id=12411160
with

```
> import requests
> `url = 'https://foodtracer.taipei.gov.tw/Front/Chain/Product?id=12411160'
>
> r = requests.post(url)
> 
> print(r.status_code) # 200
> 
> if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok: # OK!   print("OK!")`
```

But this occurred:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='foodtracer.taipei.gov.tw', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)')))

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='foodtracer.taipei.gov.tw', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)')))
```

I tried`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip` but the error still occurred.
Is there any other way for me to crawl this website?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `verify=False` in your request:

```
r = requests.post(url, verify=False)
```

This will generate a warning, though you can choose to [suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho) it.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't know why.   
Could someone explain? Is there any other way for me to do this?
 Cause this seems unsafe.

Comment: If the main issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted. SSL issue must be due to the fact that the website's SSL certificate has expired and hence can't be verified by any CA. @WinnieXi Don't think you can really do something here, it's up-to the site's administrators to provide a valid SSL certificate for their website.

Comment: You can check the website’s certificate in your browser - in the address bar it will show a lock with a line or X through it - you can click this and examine the certificate details.

Comment: what is the permenant solution for this? Verify false is a temporary soln. my browser not showing the certificate is invalid. but some requests this comes as response