# Problems with requests library

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

My code is returning an error message, but i don't know why, I've done this same logic many times before and never happened nothing like this, code below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://www.fea.usp.br/internacional/universidades-conveniadas?pais=All'
req = requests.get(site)
```

Error message:

```
- SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
- MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fea.usp.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /internacional/universidades-conveniadas?pais=All (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
- SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fea.usp.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /internacional/universidades-conveniadas?pais=All (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Comment: You may not have the issuer root certificate in your list of trusted CAs. See the requests documentation to correct that situation.

Comment: In short: the server is not properly setup to provide all necessary intermediate certificates. See [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.fea.usp.br). Recommendations on how to work around the problem are provided in the linked questions.

Answer (score -1):

The SSL certificate of the website maybe be expired, you can bypass it by making your request like this:

```
req = request.get(site, verify=False)
```

This will generate a warning, though you can [suppress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho) it.

Comment: Clearly not expired. Suppressing warnings is a bad idea unless you know for a fact you haven't been MITM'ed.

Comment: In that case, the certificate may not be installed on the local system ..

Comment: Downvoted for recommending to skip certificate problems without explicitly warning that this should (almost) never  be used in production code - and why.