# What does: "Unverified HTTPS request is being made" mean?

Tags: python, urllib3

First, I would not consider this a duplicate of [Suppress Insecure Request Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-python), but I may be wrong.

When I try to run a external script (not important what the script is doing) I get the following message:

> InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host
> `myHost.example`. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.
> See: [Urllib3 SSL-warnings](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings).

From my understanding, I know this occur because the certificate of the server which the request is being sent to has not been provided/installed by the client, but what does `Unverified HTTPS request` really mean? My understanding is that it is the same thing as when you visit a website with a untrusted certificate (e.g self signed) and are shown a warning site: "Are you sure you want to proceed?"  The traffic is still being encrypted though it is not trusted, same in this case, right?

I'd appreciate if anyone could verify this, or explain it.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct; it's exactly the same error.