# Logging in Python: Imported module starts logging at debug level after I define my own logger

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to learn how to use logging (got sick of to many print statements that I have to enable/disable) and I just added these lines to my program:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and then I am using

```
 log.debug('whatever')
```

instead of print whatever (python 2.7)

Not sure why but one of my modules (paramiko) which is imported implicitly by exscript started logging at debug level
How do I fix that ?

Comment: You probably have to go ahead and set the level separately for whatever the root logger for that module is back to your intended level.

Comment: You are correct the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234262/how-to-implement-different-levels-for-specific-modules-in-python did the trick for most of it but it seems that I can't completely disable the logging for that module (paramiko). It seems that it still has some INFO level messages. how to I disable that? What is the lowest level or how do I disable logging completely

Comment: The highest level is probably going to be ERROR or CRITICAL. You may want to allow those anyway.