# Set different module logging levels for different handlers

Tags: python, logging

I know how to adjust the level emitted from logs in individual modules

`logging.getLogger(<module>).setLevel(logging.INFO)`

[How to implement different levels for specific modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234262/how-to-implement-different-levels-for-specific-modules-in-python)

My question is - can it be customized per-handler? (I have 3 handlers - File, Network, and commandline)  (My problem is that one module, sqlalchemy, is emitting far to many messages at the info level.  My CL logger is INFO, network and file are DEBUG.  I want the messages in the network and file loggers, just not on the command line.)

Or, alternatively, is there a way to "demote" messages from a log - i.e. turn all INFO into DEBUG, for example?

Comment: Yes - we can see from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel) that `Handler`s have a `setLevel` method.

Comment: But that's for everything that emits from the handler.  I just want to change the the level of a specific log as emitted from a specific handler. 

i.e. I know i can change the StreamHandler to Warning -but that stops all messages at Info, not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Ideally, I would solve this with a filter on the source logger - and change the level of the messages originating - but I couldn't get the filter to register (I added it, but it never got called.)

**Try 1:**

```
class SA_Filter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.INFO:
           record.level = logging.DEBUG
           record.levelname = 'DEBUG'
        return True


saLogger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
saLogger.addFilter(SA_Filter())
```

**Try 2** -

so, based on this info from the [Logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) .
"Note that filters attached to handlers are consulted before an event is emitted by the handler" - I assumed that that meant prior to determining if the record should be emitted from the handler based on level, it ran the filters -

So I had this, which modified the record:

```
class SA_Filter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.name.startswith('sqlalchemy.engine') and record.levelno == logging.INFO:
           record.level = logging.DEBUG
           record.levelname = 'DEBUG'
        return True

# change info messages to Debug for sqlalchemy
handlers = logging.getLogger().handlers
for handler in handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler):
        handler.addFilter(SA_Filter())
```

However, it turns out that the sequence is:

1. Check record level against handler level
2. Run Filters
3. Emit record.

So I ended with

**Try 3**

Which runs on the handler side, and gets the handler level - if the handler is Info or above, the messages are filtered, out, ow they are emitted.

```
# create log filter to filter out sql alchemy logs at INFO level - for the commandline handler
class SA_Filter(logging.Filter):
    """a class to filter out sqlalchemy logs at INFO level - for the commandline handler"""

    def __init__(self, handler_level: int, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.handler_level = handler_level if handler_level else 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def filter(self, record):
        """
        filter out sqlalchemy logs at INFO level
        """
        # if we're dealing with sqlalchemy logs, filter them if they're at the INFO level and so is the handler.
        if record.name.startswith('sqlalchemy.engine') and record.levelno == logging.INFO and self.handler_level >= logging.INFO:
            return False
        else:
            return True

...
# change info messages to Debug for sqlalchemy
handlers = logging.getLogger().handlers
for handler in handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler):
        handler.addFilter(SA_Filter(handler.level))
```