# Properly using nullHandler to disable logging messages from a particular package

Tags: python, logging, configuration-files

I want to stop an external module to flood my logging file, like in this question:
[Disable logging for a particular package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326012/disable-logging-for-a-particular-package)
The config file inspired by the answer is below. I use python3.2

My problem is, it does not work: the line 'handlers=nullHandler' raises this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tree_browser", line 44, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('../log/logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 79, in fileConfig
    _install_loggers(cp, handlers, disable_existing_loggers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 202, in _install_loggers
    log.addHandler(handlers[hand])
KeyError: 'nullHandler'
```

And I find no way to use this nullHandler.
The config file is:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,RPIO

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=defaultFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler

[logger_RPIO]
level=NOTSET
handlers=nullHandler
qualname=_RPIO.py
propagate=0

[handler_nullHandler]
class=NullHandler
level=DEBUG

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=defaultFormatter
filemode=w
args=('../log/pilberry_core.log',)

[formatter_defaultFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(filename)s: %(funcName)s: %(message)s
datefmt=%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
```

Other attempts that failed: tried without defining a [handler_nullHandler], using either nullHandler or NullHandler as formatter, it always fails the same way.

Note that if I disable the RPIO_logger (by removing RPIO from the [loggers] keys sections), then the rest works fine.

So, what's the proper way to use the nullHandler?

Comment: After I got a similar error I had to also specify `args=()` in handler configuration and level is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `handlers` section, you only list `fileHandler`. So, when you read in that config, it builds a `handlers` dictionary with only `fileHandler`. So, when you try to use `nullHandler`, you get a `KeyError`, because it's not in the dictionary.

I'm guessing this was a simple typo, but if not, see [Configuration file format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format) in the docs:

> The file must contain sections called [loggers], [handlers] and [formatters] which identify by name the entities of each type which are defined in the file. For each such entity, there is a separate section which identifies how that entity is configured.

In other words, just having a `handler_nullHandler` section doesn't create a handler named `nullHandler`; having `keys=…,nullHandler,…` in the `handlers` section does that.

Comment: How does adding null handler to child logger prevent root logger from displaying log messages?